# ASP.Net MVC Postback does not clear textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textbox, postback

On a .cshtml page I have a single textbox inside a form. When I enter some text and press return it triggers a POST to a controller of the same name (different signature). The code processes the text and a model is created and passed back to the same page where in addition to the original textbox a grid is now populated (conditionally). Everything works, except the text in the textbox is retained.

This is a little odd, considering that most of the questions on here are about retaining the text after a POST and the indication has been that the text should not automatically be retained.

I can probably assign the textbox an empty string but I am simply wondering if I have this wrong?

Comment: I believe you passed the model object with return view(<model object>). Remove that from here.

Comment: This may be restatement of what @KundanSinghChouhan said, but did you create a new model to your View? Or did you pass back the same model that was sent to your post method?

Comment: Hi In your question, you have mentioned ‘The code processes the text and **a model is created and passed back** to the same page..’ Assuming your view is strongly typed and the textbox is rendered off a property of the model, you should be able to use a breakpoint just before you return the model for the second time and check the value of the property. I also have a strong suspicion just as @Kundan Singh Chouhan mentioned that you may be using the model which was return to you by the first post.

Comment: Thank you for all responses.

Comment: The textbox is the only object in the posted form. The text entered is compared to existing data and the outcome is to either create a model that includes the entry and related data or to simply return a string indicating the result. So if the entry dosen't match any existing entry, then no model is ceated and just the string is returned. I found I was unable to change the form data in code and so have chosen to use jQuery to empty the textbox when the page is created.

Comment: However, since the textbox is created as: @Html.Textbox("name",""), with an empty string as the second parameter this behavior still seems a little odd.In testing I have to accept the first answer below and conclude that the posted data is being returned back to the browser as a named pair and overriding the value of the textbox. Rather than use jQuery to overwrite the textbox, I would think it better to intecept the returned form data, so perhaps someone knows how to do this they could advise.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it was a simple textbox, html textbox is a input control that has two very important properties, i.e.

1. name
2. value

browser will send this name value pair to server
***and the default behavior of server is to return the collection of all pairs back to browser*** when its done whatever it was supposed to do.

this collection is called post data. (or sometimes form data)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could clear the textbox in code if everything was fine on postback

If something was wrong (exception or validation) you could  do nothing ( as you do now) and text will be there again, what's makes sense in the UI
.